# Interesting fixed element issue when page scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page and fixed menu(display:none) and if I scroll page until rezervation form fixed menu make it appear it's good so far but if my resulution under 768px my fixed menu doesn't work when I scroll page until I refresh..

Edit: I undserstand problem..problem is top navigation menu(mega menu) if I remove it my codes work but I have to solve not removing

JS

```
$(function() {
    if (!$(".hotel-search-box").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height() && $(".oda-otel-giris").val() == ""){
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeIn(500);
      }else{
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeOut(500);
      }
  });
});
```

CSS

```
  .sticky-checkin{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:1042;
        background:#FFF;
        width:100%;
        padding:15px 0;
        @include clearfix;
     -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 10px 7px -9px rgba(61,61,61,0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 10px 7px -9px rgba(61,61,61,0.36);
    box-shadow: -1px 10px 7px -9px rgba(61,61,61,0.36);
    display:none;
    }
    .sticky-container{
        width:50%;
        position: relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        @include clearfix;
        input,select{
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    }

    /**
     * sticky border
     */
    .oteller-sticky{
        border-bottom:1px solid #faa82b;
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="sticky-checkin oteller-sticky">
                  <div class="sticky-container">
                      <div class="row mt10">
                       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 mb10">
                          <input type="text" name="oda-otel-giris"  class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width sticky-oda-giris" placeholder="Giriş" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupCheckin">
                            <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 ">
                         <input type="text" name="oda-otel-cikis"  class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width sticky-oda-cikis" placeholder="Çıkış" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupCheckin">
                            <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                  </div><!-- sticky container-->
                   <div class="modal fade fullscreen" id="popupCheckin"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog otel-filtreleme-popup">
                          <div class="modal-content" style="color:#fff;">
                              <div class="modal-header" style="border:1px solid orange;">
                                      <h3>OTEL BUL</h3>
                                      <button type="button" class="close btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-close fa-lg" style="color:#faa82b;"></i></button> 
                                      <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><span class="sr-only">main navigation</span></h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body otel-filtreleme-popup">
                                  <div class="container-margin nomargin nopadding notopmargin">
                                      <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 otel-arama">
                                            <input type="text" name="oda-otel" id="oda-otel" class="oda-otel input-full-width" placeholder="Otel adını veya Bölgeyi yaz">
                                            <span class="oda-otel-icon"></span>
                                          </div>
                                      </div><!-- otel ara-->
                                      <div class="row mt10">
                                         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 mb10">
                                            <input type="text" name="oda-otel-giris" class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width" placeholder="Giriş">
                                              <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                           <input type="text" name="oda-otel-cikis" class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width" placeholder="Çıkış">
                                              <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                                         </div>
                                     </div><!-- otel giriş çıkış-->
                                     <div class="row ">
                                       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                        <select name="oda-otel-kisi" id="oda-otel-kisi" class="oda-otel-kisi" style="display: none;">
                                          <option value="">Kişi</option>
                                          <option value="">1 Kişi</option>
                                          <option value="">2 Kişi</option>
                                          <option value="">3 Kişi</option>
                                        </select><div class="nice-select oda-otel-kisi" tabindex="0"><span class="current">Kişi</span><ul class="list"><li data-value="" class="option selected">Kişi</li><li data-value="" class="option">1 Kişi</li><li data-value="" class="option">2 Kişi</li><li data-value="" class="option">3 Kişi</li></ul></div><span class="oda-otel-kisi-icon"></span>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning otel-oda-sec" value="OTEL ARA">
                                      </div>
                                     </div><!-- otel kişi sayısı-->
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                  </div><!-- /.fullscreen -->
              </div><!-- sticky checkin-->
```

[online demo](http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2016/test/otel-listeleme.html)